# Обновить данные на странице без ее перезагрузки gin-gonic

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, golang, golang-gin

Можно ли обновить часть кода страницы, получив данные из функции `go`, с помошью `gin-gonic`. Подскажите где копать, а лучше поделитесь частью кода как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

В свое время помог этот тред: http://nirbhay.in/blog/2013/03/ajax-with-go/

А вообще можете погуглить ajax requests with go lang

Comment: А через gin-gonic не подскажешь как сделать. Вчера весь день просидел за ним так и не понял.

Comment: Ajax-запрос – это ровно такой же запрос на сервер, как и тот, что выполняется при вбивании адреса в строку браузера. Отличие лишь в том, что обычно на ajax-запрос отвечают json'ом, а не отрендеренной html-страницей для экономии трафика

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ, как уже сказали выше, это выполнить ajax-запрос и вернуть с сервера результат выполнения в формате JSON.

Например, возьмем всем опостылевший jQuery со стороны клиента (браузера) и gin-gonic на стороне сервера:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
или более простые в использовании функции http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ и http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.get("/ajax/testurl", function( data ) {
  console.log(data); // выводим объект, который пришел с сервера в консоль браузера 
  $(".result-text").html(data.text); // в содержимое элемента с классом result-text кладем содержимое поля text из объекта
});
```

На сервере делаем новый роут под это (на примере gin-gonic):

```
router.GET("/ajax/testurl", func(c *gin.Context) {
    // ... тут всякая бизнес логика
    text := DoSomethingAndReturnText()
    // Выводим результат в формате JSON
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "text":  text,
    })
})
```